# Regex a partir de Scanner en Java

Tags: java, regex

ocurre lo siguiente:
En mi clase le pido al usuario que escriba la palabra de la que quiere obtener el patrón, luego le pido que ingrese el patrón a identificar, pero al ejecutar mi programa solo captura la info y no pasa al método patrón, ¿Alguna idea de por qué, o cómo arreglarlo? Gracias, pego el código:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


class MasRegex {

    static String c1,c2;
    private static Scanner obDatos,obDatos2;
    private static Matcher m;
    private static Pattern p;

    public String DatosAnalizar() {
        System.out.println("Ingresa la palabra a analizar");
        c1=obDatos.next();
        return c1;
    }

    public String DatosPatron() {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el patróna  buscar");
        c2=obDatos2.nextLine(); 
        return c2;
    }

    public void Patron(String c1,String c2) {
        p=Pattern.compile(c1);
        m=p.matcher(c2);

        while(m.find()) { 
            System.out.println("Patrón encontrado");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MasRegex r=new MasRegex();
        obDatos= new Scanner(System.in);
        obDatos2= new Scanner(System.in);
        r.DatosAnalizar();
        r.DatosPatron();
        r.Patron(c1, c2);   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. Estás usando c1 como patrón y c2 como texto y creo que van al contrario. Si haces

   ```
   p=Pattern.compile(c2);
   m=p.matcher(c1);
   ```

Funciona como se espera.

2. No imprimes nada cuando no encuentra el patrón en el texto. Sí entra al método siempre pero, como estás buscando mal, no encuntras nada y termina correctamente. Procura considerar estos casos en tus programas para controlarlos, mostrar algo en pantalla, etc.

No estaría de más que uses nombres significativos en tus variables que por eso es que c1 no dice nada y no sabemos si transporta un texto o un patrón.
Así mismo, como buena práctica los nombres de los métodos deben comenzar con minúscula.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya corrió :)